# How to pass generic array as open array parameter in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I have an enumerated type and I need to pass an array of this type as parameter:

```
type
  TTest = (a,b,c);


procedure DoTest(stest: TArray<TTest>);
```

When I compile

```
DoTest([a]);
```

I receiv the error below:

> Error: E2010 Incompatible types: 'System.TArray' and 'Set'*

So, how can I call `DoTest` without creating a variable of type `TArray<TTest>`?

Comment: `TArray<Ttest>` is not an open array parameter - `array of Ttest` would be.

Comment: @StefanGlienke, yes that is clearly a misunderstanding of how such a parameter is called.

Comment: Your question is quite odd. Think about it. "I have a function that accepts `TArray<TTest>`. How can I call it without passing a `TArray<TTest>`?" Surely it's obvious that you cannot do that. Change the function to accept an open array parameter.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "...Change the function to accept an open array parameter." How do it with enum type?

Comment: Read the documentation for open array parameters. If you do that will be obvious. Always harder when you haven't read documentation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan to read the documentation I need to know the definition of what I want. as I did not know the term "open array", I thought that would be the best way here. I am not a graduate in programming. Thanks for nothing

Comment: Hard to reconcile that claim not to know what open array parameter is given the title of this question. You just typed those words completely by accident. Seriously, read documentation. Don't give up. It's so much easier if you read documentation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're completely right. It is not possible to do this using the generic array (at least in Delphi XE5). He was not fully understanding the definition of open matrix, so he said he did not know. Excuse me for the previous harsh words.

Comment: When you say he you mean I or are you sharing an account?

Comment: I'm sorry... i'm Brazilian. I Wrote "Ele" in portuguese on Google translate that is similar to "Eu"(I)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do what you want is to change the parameter to an [open array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Open_Arrays) of TTest, i.e.

```
procedure DoTest(const stest: array of TTest);
```

But supposed you don't want to change the parameter, and really want it to be a `TArray<TTest>`, then you can simply use the array pseudo-constructor syntax to call it (in almost all versions of Delphi, except the very old ones). Say you have something like:

```
type
  TTest = (a, b, c);

procedure DoTest(const stest: TArray<TTest>);
// simple demo implementation
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := Low(stest) to High(stest) do
    Write(Integer(stest[I]), ' ');
  Writeln;
end;
```

Then it can be called, using the Create syntax without having to declare a variable or having to fill it manually. The compiler will do this for you:

```
begin
  DoTest(TArray<TTest>.Create(a, c, b, a, c));
end.
```

The output is, as expected:

```
0 2 1 0 2
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a Delphi compiler available right now, so I cannot verify this, but to me

```
procedure DoTest(stest: TArray<TTest>);
```

doesn't declare `stest` as an [open array parameter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Open_Array_Parameters), but a dynamic array parameter. You do want

```
procedure DoTest(const stest: array of TTest);
```

Comment: @LURD: Without a Delphi compiler available, I cannot answer that. (Also, it might have changed in XE7.)

Comment: Shameless plug: [Open array parameters and array of const](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html), written by me.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler may confuse `a` with another declaration.

Qualify the type like this:

```
DoTest([Ttest.a]);
```

**Note:**

This feature of initializing dynamic arrays was introduced in [XE7](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE7#String-Like_Operations_Supported_on_Dynamic_Arrays).

Comment: I tested this with Delphi 2010 and it gives the same error OP posts (compiler thinks it is a set, not array).

Comment: @ain, this was a feature introduced in XE7.

Comment: OK, the OP should specify his Delphi version and what he means with "without var" (ie is my solution "creating an var" or not)

Comment: "How can I call `DoTest` without creating a variable of type `TArray<TTest>`?"

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, how do you create a variable of type `TArray<TTest>?`. My answer works well in XE7+ and initializes a dynamic array.

Comment: The error message indicates that the compiler predates dynamic array constants. And the edit confirms that.

Comment: And even if it were XE7+, then the qualification would not be necessary. After all, this function is not overloaded and the compiler expects a  `TArray<TTest>`, so it accepts values like a, b or c.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, I did a test before publishing. You are wrong. If there is a variable named a,b or c in scope, the compiler complaines.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, put the `TTest` and `DoTest` in a separate unit and compile: `program Project52; {$APPTYPE CONSOLE} uses Unit10 in 'Unit10.pas'; var a : Integer; begin DoTest([a]); end.` This gives `[dcc32 Error] Project52.dpr(11): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TTest' and 'Integer'`

Comment: @LURD: Well of course. You have a conflicting identifier nearer in scope. But otherwise, there is no need to fully qualify. One would generally choose unique identifiers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that with "how can I call DoTest without creating a variable of type TArray" you want to avoid declaring and initializing local variable, ie code like

```
var arr: TArray<TTest>;
begin
  SetLength(arr, 1);
  arr[0] := a;
  DoTest(arr);
```

For this you can use the array constructor like:

```
DoTest(TArray<TTest>.Create(a));
```

This syntaxs is supported at least since Delphi 2010.

Comment: *how call DoTest wihout create a var of array of TTest*

Comment: Hmm, I think the OP means without a local variable... creating an array "inline" is not the same?

Comment: Either way, this produces the same code as my answer if the compiler supports the XE7 introduced way of initializing dynamic arrays.

Comment: "How can I call `DoTest` without creating a variable of type `TArray<TTest>`?"

Comment: @DavidHeffernan As I already commented, I think the OP wants to avoid creating an local variable, ie code like `var arr: TArray<TTest>; SetLength(arr, 1); arr[0] := a; DoTest(arr);`

Comment: @ain Difficult to know what is meant when the terminology is imprecise. You declare variables and create objects. You don't create variables.

Comment: What about `DoTest(TArray<TTest>.Create(a, b));`?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis What about it? It works fine. Actually my first answer had example using two elements but Remy edited it to only have one, supposedly to match the question...